# Bootstrap Dropdown link selected value to input field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Boostrap Dropdown as a search form using the code below. When an option is selected from the dropdown menu, it populates a hidden input field which is then posted to the PHP results page when the form is submitted.

**HTML**

```
<div id="search-form">
<form action="results.php" method="post">

<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Location<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><input type="hidden" id="property_location" name="property_location" value=""></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="#">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="City 1">City 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="City 2">City 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="City 3">City 3</a></li>
</ul></div>

<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Min Bedrooms<span class="caret"></span></a>
ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><input type="hidden" id="property_rooms" name="property_rooms" value=""></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="0">Min Bedrooms</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="3">3</a></li>
</ul></div>

<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Min Price<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><input type="hidden" id="property_pricemin" name="property_pricemin" value=""></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="0">Min Price</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="100">100</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="200">200</a></li>
</ul></div>

<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Max Price<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><input type="hidden" id="property_pricemax" name="property_pricemax" value=""></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="1000">Max Price</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="300">300</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="500">500</a></li>
</ul></div>

<input type="submit" title="Search" class="btn-round" value="Search"/>
</form>     
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
var selText = $(this).text();
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+'<span class="caret"></span>');
$('#property_location').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

The code above works for the first dropdown menu, but I have three other dropdowns on the page which all need to have a separate input field populated. Each input field has a separate ID, so I have tried amending the JS code as below, but this changes all four dropdown's when any option is selected?

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
var selText = $(this).text();
$(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+'<span class="caret"></span>');
$('#property_location').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
$('#property_rooms').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
$('#property_pricemin').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
$('#property_pricemax').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know why are you selecting all the hidden inputs and put the current value in all of them.

You need to do sth like this:

```
$(this).parents(".dropdown-menu").find("input").val($(this).attr('data-value'));
```

This way you fill with value only the hidden input from the current dropdown